# Syntax using WHERE in Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

In a members database I'm trying to find embers with "round" ages this year. Have tried this statement, but get "syntax error for the WHERE part:

```
SELECT name, born, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,born,CURDATE()) AS age WHERE MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,born,CURDATE()),10)IS NULL FROM Members;
```

Separately both `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and `MOD` are ok. I'm using Mysql 5.5.38 under Ubuntu.

Comment: `MOD(n)` shouldn't return `NULL`. Do you mean `MOD(...)=0`?

Comment: Order of statements is important in SQL... SELECT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY

Comment: Thanks taxman, I just found out a minute before reading your answer. Also thanks to Pantamtuy and JayL for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think the from needs to be before the where clause.

```
SELECT name, born, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,born,CURDATE()) AS age 
FROM Members
WHERE MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,born,CURDATE()),10)IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, born, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,born,CURDATE()) AS age 
FROM Members
WHERE MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,born,CURDATE()),10) = 0
```